# Não consigo criar classe em php e usar conexão com PDO

Tags: php, pdo

Estou criando uma classe que busca dados do banco para ser exibida.
Por exemplo, uma das funções da classe é pegar a data, de um dado, no banco e exibir na tela. Do jeito que estou fazendo, não está dando certo.

Segue meu código

```
<?php

class contaEntrada {

var $dataConta;
var $descricaoConta;
var $valorConta;

function conectar(){
    $host = "localhost";
    $user = "root";
    $pass = "root";
    $dbname = "fluxo_de_caixa";

    try {
        $opcoes = array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=fluxo_de_caixa;", "root", "root", $opcoes);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
    return $pdo;
}

function pegaDataConta(){
    $pdo = conectar();
    $pegaData=$pdo->prepare("SELECT data FROM entrada WHERE id_entrada:id");
    $pegaData->bindValue(":id", 30);
    $pegaData->execute();
}

function mostraConta(){
    echo $this->descricaoConta = "Conta de luz";
}

function valorConta(){
    echo $this->valorConta = "50,00";
}
}
```

E estou chamando as funções em outro arquivo.
index.php

```
<?php
require_once "con/conexao.php";
require_once "classes/contaEntrada.php";

$entrada = new contaEntrada();

$entrada->pegaDataConta();
echo " - ";
$entrada->mostraConta();
echo " - ";
$entrada->valorConta();
```

Comment: `id_entrada = :id` e depois do execute, poderias usar o método _fetch_ para retornar o conjunto referente a essa consulta.

Answer (score 1):

Se isso for teu código completo, pode ser que você tenha se esquecido de  chamar a função `pegaDataConta()`, se já estiver chamando ela, abaixo do `$pegaData->execute()` faça um  `var_dump($pegaData->fetchAll());` para mostrar todos os dados na página.

Peguei seu código e alterei para um banco mysql meu e funciona perfeitamente, tente assim:

```
<?php

function conectar(){
    $user = 'root';
    $pass = 'root';
    try {
        $opcoes = array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=fluxo_de_caixa', $user, $pass, $opcoes);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
    return $pdo;
}

function pegaDataConta(){
    $pdo = conectar();
    $pegaData =$pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM entrada");
    $pegaData->execute();
    var_dump($pegaData->fetchAll());
}

pegaDataConta();
```

Se for outro problema me avise que edito a resposta, fora isto esta tudo normal no seu código.

Comment: Oi @GabrielRodrigues,
Cara, estou chamando a função em outro arquivo, veja:


require_once "con/conexao.php";
require_once "classes/contaEntrada.php";

$entrada = new contaEntrada();

$entrada->pegaDataConta();

$entrada->mostraConta();

$entrada->valorConta();

Comment: Então gustavo, no  final da função PegaDataConta você tem que retornar os valores, você pode fazer um return $pegaData->fetchAll();  e depois exbir usando var_dump($entrada->pegaDataConta(););

Answer (score 1):

```
function pegaDataConta(){
    $pdo = conectar();
    $pegaData=$pdo->prepare("SELECT data FROM entrada WHERE id_entrada:id");
    $pegaData->bindValue(":id", 30);
    $pegaData->execute();
}
```

Não esqueça de colocara operação que deseja, no caso seria igual, está faltando um na consulta também faça o método retornar os dados obtidos com `fetch()` ou `fetch()`

```
function pegaDataConta(){
    $pdo = conectar();
    $pegaData=$pdo->prepare("SELECT data FROM entrada WHERE id_entrada = :id");
    $pegaData->bindValue(":id", 30);
    if(!$pegaData->execute()){
       print_r($pdo->errorInfo);
    }
    return $pegaData->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Sugestões:

Não use a palavra chave `var` ele serve para definir um propriedade da classa no **php4**, use algum dos modificadores de acesso, `public`, `protected` ou `private`.

É melhor criar um atributo de classe para guardar a conexão, uma vez criado ele no construtor é só chamar.

Comment: estou chamando a função pegaDataConta em outro arquivo.

require_once "con/conexao.php";
require_once "classes/contaEntrada.php";

$entrada = new contaEntrada();

$entrada->pegaDataConta();

$entrada->mostraConta();

$entrada->valorConta();

Comment: @GustavoSevero e qual é o problema?

Comment: Não mostra a data que está no banco.

Comment: Mas na atualização da pergunta vc não da echo no resultado do método.

Comment: @GustavoSevero como está agora o método `pegaDataConta()`

Comment: Está assim:

unction pegaDataConta(){
  //echo $this->dataConta = date("d/m/Y");
  $pdo = conectar();
  $pegaData=$pdo->prepare("SELECT data FROM entrada WHERE id_entrada=:id");
  $pegaData->bindValue(":id", 30);
  if(!$pegaData->execute()){
      print_r($pdo->errorInfo);
  }
  return $pegaData->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
 }

pois sugeriram que eu fizesse isso para ver o que retornava, mas nada acontece.

Comment: @GustavoSevero, faça `print_r($entrada->pegaDataConta());` veja o que retorna, diga mesmo q seja um array vazio.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30880/discussion-between-gustavosevero-and-rray).

Comment: Cara, troquei no IF:

print_r($pdo->errorInfo);
por
print_r($entrada->pegaDataConta());
e não aparece nada ainda.

Faço esse comando tirando o IF ou assim como fiz?

Comment: @GustavoSevero, assim, depois que criar o objeto: `$entrada = new contaEntrada(); print_r($entrada->pegaDataConta());`

Comment: Ahhhhh, perfeito.

Comment: Olha, fiz o que disseste, mas agora da erro na página.

"Server error

500"

Comment: No início do scrpt, coloque, `ini_set('display_errors', true); error_reporting(E_ALL);` e veja o que aparece, @GustavoSevero

Comment: Acho que com sua ajuda na outra pergunta, consigo tocar o barco.
Para quem precisar... [http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/95424/como-manipular-dados-vindos-do-banco-usando-pdo/95426#95426]