# Como manipular dados vindos do banco usando PDO

Tags: php, pdo

Estou começando a usar PDO nos meu projetos em PHP.
Quando eu trabalhava com mysql, sem PDO, quando eu pegava uma consulta no BD, eu consegui pegar cada dado associando a uma variável e poderia fazer o que eu queria com ela.
Agora usando PDO, como eu posso fazer essa manipulação de dados?

Poe exemplo:
Eu fazia isso..

```
$contas_entrada = mysql_query("SELECT valor FROM entrada WHERE id_empresa='$id_empresa' ORDER BY data DESC");
while($entrada_row = mysql_fetch_array($contas_entrada)){
$valor = $entrada_row['valor'];
}
```

Então eu poderia trabalhar em cima da variável $valor para mexer nela.
Como posso pegar dados, via PDO, para manipulá-los?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não é dificil converter o código:

```
$sql = "SELECT valor FROM entrada WHERE id_empresa = :id ORDER BY data DESC";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
if($stmt->execute(array(':id' => $id))){
    print_r($stmt->errorInfo);
}

$itens = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$total = 0;
foreach($itens as $item){
    $total += $item['valor'];
}
```

Ou pode usar a variante while/fetch()

```
$total = 0;
while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    $total += $row['valor'];
}
```

Comment: Beleza, vou tentar @rray.
A minha outra pergunta, ainda não consegui solução.
Você tem email para nos falarmos?
Abs.

Comment: eu me acostumei a fazer a consulta, dessa forma:

$pegaData=$pdo->prepare("SELECT data FROM entrada WHERE id_entrada=:id");
$pegaData->bindValue(":id", 30);

Como posso fazer pra pegar a data, a partir daqui?

Comment: `$pegaData=$pdo->prepare("SELECT data FROM entrada WHERE id_entrada=:id");
$pegaData->bindValue(":id", 30);
$pegaData->execute();
$res = $pegaData->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
print_r($res);` @GustavoSevero

Comment: Agora apareceu...

"Array ( [0] => Array ( [data] => 2014-05-05 ) ) - Conta de luz - 50,00"

Comment: @GustavoSevero, significa que funcionou! :D. Use o `fetchAll()` quando vc sabe que a consulta retornara várias linhas e `fetch()` quando retornar apenas uma linha.

Comment: Certo, vou ver isso.

Comment: Perfeito, consegui. Valeu.
Me passa seu email?

Comment: @GustavoSevero, passo so espera eu chegar em casa

Comment: Claro! Hehehehehe

Comment: @GustavoSevero ta ai?